# Pass input to bash script using java input stream and collect bash script output to java output stream using thread

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, stream, processbuilder

I am trying to pass input to bash script using java input stream and collect bash script output to java output stream using two different thread.

my bash script is:
    #!/bin/sh 
    echo "added at start"
    while read LINE; do 
       echo $LINE
    done

and my Java code is:

```
public class NewRedirector implements Runnable {

private static final int BULK_BUFFER_SIZE = 500000;
private static final int READ_BUFFER_SIZE = 250000;

private static final int OFFSET = 0;
private final OutputStream targetStream;
private final InputStream sourceStream;
private final boolean useChannel;

public NewRedirector(InputStream sourceStream , OutputStream targetStream, boolean useChannel) {
    this.sourceStream = sourceStream;
    this.targetStream = targetStream;
    this.useChannel = useChannel;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    byte[] readbyte = new byte[READ_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int dataSize = 0;
    try {
        if(targetStream instanceof FileOutputStream && useChannel) {
            FileChannel targetFC = ((FileOutputStream) targetStream).getChannel();
            try {
            if(sourceStream instanceof FileInputStream && useChannel) {
                FileChannel sourceFC = ((FileInputStream) sourceStream).getChannel();
                ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(BULK_BUFFER_SIZE);
                bb.clear();
                dataSize = 0;
                while ((dataSize = sourceFC.read(bb)) > 0) {
                    bb.flip();
                    while (bb.hasRemaining()) {
                        targetFC.write(bb);
                    }
                    bb.clear();
                }
            } else {
                ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(BULK_BUFFER_SIZE);
                dataSize = 0;
                while ((dataSize = sourceStream.read(readbyte)) > 0) {
                    if(BULK_BUFFER_SIZE > bb.position() + dataSize) {
                        bb.put(readbyte, OFFSET, dataSize);
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        bb.flip();
                        targetFC.write(bb);
                        bb.clear();
                    }
                    bb.put(readbyte, OFFSET, dataSize);
                }
                if(bb.position() > 0) {
                    bb.flip();
                    targetFC.write(bb);
                    bb.clear();
                }
            }
            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Got Exception: " + e);
            } finally {
                if(targetFC != null && targetFC.isOpen()) {
                    targetFC.close();
                    targetFC = null;
                }
            }
        } else {
            BufferedOutputStream btarget = new BufferedOutputStream(targetStream);
            try {
            if (sourceStream instanceof FileInputStream && useChannel) {
                FileChannel sourceFC = ((FileInputStream) sourceStream).getChannel();
                ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(BULK_BUFFER_SIZE);
                bb.clear();
                dataSize = 0;
                while ((dataSize = sourceFC.read(bb)) > 0) {
                    bb.position(OFFSET);
                    bb.limit(dataSize);
                    while (bb.hasRemaining()) {
                        dataSize = Math.min(bb.remaining(), READ_BUFFER_SIZE);
                        bb.get(readbyte, OFFSET, dataSize);
                        btarget.write(readbyte, OFFSET, dataSize);
                    }
                    btarget.flush();
                    bb.clear();
                }
            } else {
                dataSize = 0;
                while ((dataSize = sourceStream.read(readbyte)) > 0) {
                    btarget.write(readbyte, OFFSET, dataSize);
                }
                btarget.flush();
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Got Exception: " + e);
        } finally {
            if(btarget != null) {
                btarget.close();
                btarget = null;
            }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Got Exception: " + e);
    }
}
```

}

and

```
public class NewProcessExecutor {

public static void main(String ... args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    NewProcessExecutor pe = new NewProcessExecutor();
    pe.startProcessinputfromstreamoutputtostreamintwothread();
}

private void startProcessinputfromstreamoutputtostreamintwothread()
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String lscriptLocation = "/scratch/demo/RunScript/append.sh";

    File inFile = new File("/scratch/demo/Source/inFile");
    File outFile = new File("/scratch/demo/Source/outFile");

    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(lscriptLocation);
    /*processBuilder.redirectInput(Redirect.PIPE);
    processBuilder.redirectOutput(Redirect.PIPE);*/
    Process process = processBuilder.start();       

    if(Redirect.PIPE.file() == null && Redirect.PIPE.type() == Redirect.Type.PIPE) {
        System.out.println("IO connected over PIPE");
    }

    //startStreamRedirector(new FileInputStream(inFile), process.getOutputStream());
    startStreamRedirector(process.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream(outFile));
    int exitvalue = process.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Exit value: " + exitvalue);

    if (exitvalue != 0) {
        System.out.println("Script execution failed with error: "
                + readErrorStream(process.getErrorStream()));
        return;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Script executed successfully, please see output file: " + outFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}

private String readErrorStream(InputStream errorStream) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try (BufferedReader buffR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            errorStream))) {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = buffR.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Got Exception: " + e);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private void startStreamRedirector(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) {
    new Thread(new NewRedirector(inputStream, outputStream, true)).start();

}
```

}

Now the problem is this code sometime runs perfectly but some times it creates zero size file.

Can someone point out what could be the issue?
As per my information default redirect is PIPE so hope I don't need set redirect input and output to PIPE.

```
processBuilder.redirectInput(Redirect.PIPE)
```

Comment: Is exit code==0 in both cases?

Comment: @Antoniossss yes in both the case

Comment: Then most likely it is env related - maybe external script is not writing any output at all, maybe it is printing something to the stderr and stops with 0 code. Hard to tell for me. As a last idea from me you can try to redirect stderr to stdout and see what happens

Comment: @Antoniossss, actually this code works perfectly because here output collector thread is writing to FileOutputStream and it is being closed only in this thread so here even after main thread execution ends underlying stream works fine. But in my actual project target outputstream(in this case file) could be anything and main thread also can close it. so whenever main thread execution ends before collector thread, collector thread finds stream is already closed.... Thanks for your help..